# Cannot override to_s in irb

Tags: ruby

I defined a function :to_s in pry, but I am not able to call it. Where does this method go and how can I call it?

```
pry(main)> def to_s
pry(main)*   'hello'
pry(main)* end
pry(main)> to_s
=> "main"
```

My ruby version is 2.1.2

### After reading some answers and searching, I think I have got the right answer:

1. Where does this method to?

when define a method in irb or pry, it goes to  `Object.instance_methods`

```
[1] pry(main)> def to_s
[1] pry(main)*   'hello'
[1] pry(main)* end
=> :to_s
[2] pry(main)> def hello
[2] pry(main)*   'world'
[2] pry(main)* end
=> :hello
[4] pry(main)> Object.instance_methods(false)
=> [:pry, :__binding__, :to_s, :hello]
```

2. How can I call it?

These new methods can be called in a new object.

```
[6] pry(main)> Object.new.to_s
=> "hello"
```

The reason I'm not able to call to_s in top-level is that `main` is a special object which defined a `#to_s` and `#inspect` method.

```
[5] pry(main)> singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
=> [:to_s, :inspect]
```

Answer (score 4):

@Anthony's answer explains the context. To define your own `to_s` at this level, you could do it this way:

```
pry(main)> to_s
=> "main"
pry(main)> def self.to_s
pry(main)*   'hello'
pry(main)* end
pry(main)> to_s
=> "hello"
```

Comment: I first answered with this too but the difference is that you could do `def foo; 'hi'; end` and if you call `foo` it returns `hi`.  OP is writing instance methods at the top level so I updated my answer to explain the behavior she's seeing.

Answer (score 3):

You're actually at the top level [`Object class#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-to_s) method which as the docs states:

> Returns a string representing obj. The default to_s prints the
>   object’s class and an encoding of the object id. As a special case,
>   the top-level object that is the initial execution context of Ruby
>   programs returns “main”.

Comment: But if you define a method with another name like :far or :bar, You don't need this additional self, why?

Comment: Because those aren't overridden by any subclasses of `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Methods defined at the toplevel become `private` instance methods of `Object`.

So,

```
def to_s; 'hello' end
```

is equivalent to

```
class Object; private def to_s; 'hello' end end
```

And message sends without an explicit receiver are implicitly sent to `self`.

So,

```
to_s
```

is equivalent to

```
self.to_s
```

At the top-level, `self` is the nameless top-level object, usually called `main`.

Now, if any of the classes of `main` override `Object#to_s`, then the overridden version will be called. And in fact, `to_s` *is* overridden in the singleton class of `main`:

```
method(:to_s).owner
# => #<Class:#<Object:0x007fb5210c1c68>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, admittedly verbose, way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to manipulate the "current" class, like so:

```
class << self
  def to_s
    "hello"
  end
end
```